# Python changes an empty list to an integer

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

so I my problem was to write a function statement() that takes as input a list of floating-point numbers, with positive numbers representing deposits to and negative numbers representing with- drawals from a bank account. Your function should return a list of two floating-point num- ber; the first will be the sum of the deposits, and the second (a negative number) will be the sum of the withdrawals.

And the one that I wrote seems to be changing the withdrawal empty list to the value 0, thus not allowing the append function to work. I was wondering if there was a reason python is doing this, or if its merely a weird error?

Here's the code for reference:

```
def statement(lst):
"""returns a list of two numbers; the first is the sum of the
   positive numbers (deposits) in list lst, and the second is
   the sum of the negative numbers (withdrawals)"""
deposits, withdrawals, final = [], [], []
for l in lst:
    print(l)
    if l < 0:
        print('the withdrawals are ', withdrawals)  # test
        withdrawals.append(l)
        print('the withdrawals are ', withdrawals)  # test
    else:
        print('the deposits are', deposits)  # test
        deposits.append(l)
        print('the deposits are', deposits)  # test
    withdrawals = sum(withdrawals)
    deposits = sum(deposits)
    final.append(deposits)
    final.append(withdrawals)
```

Comment: Why are you using the same name for a different value? `withdrawals = sum(withdrawals)` means you no longer have any way to refer to the list that used to be in `withdrawals`. Just don't do that and you don't have the problem: `total_withdrawals = sum(withdrawals)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines:

```
withdrawals = sum(withdrawals)
deposits = sum(deposits)
final.append(deposits)
final.append(withdrawals)
```

need to be written as:

```
final.append(sum(deposits))
final.append(sum(withdrawals))
```

Otherwise, the variables `withdrawals` and `deposits` will be rebound to the integer objects returned by `sum`.  In other words, they will no longer refer to the list objects created here:

```
deposits, withdrawals, final = [], [], []
```

Comment: This is because for loops do not form an extra scope in Python.

Comment: Or just don't reuse the same names in a confusing way, and this problem wouldn't arise in the first place…

Comment: @abarnert - Agreed.  I didn't give that as a solution however because those extra variable names are unnecessary when `sum(deposits)` and `sum(withdrawals)` can be in-lined so easily.  In this case, extra variables would just be code clutter. :)